# Get all the stored procedures from all databases in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Can anyone please advise on a way to retrieve a listing of all stored procedures along with their schema names in all database? Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #x(db SYSNAME, s SYSNAME, p SYSNAME);

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'INSERT #x SELECT ''' + name + ''',s.name, p.name
  FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.schemas AS s
  INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.procedures AS p
  ON p.schema_id = s.schema_id;
' FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id > 4

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

SELECT db,s,p FROM #x ORDER BY db,s,p;

DROP TABLE #x;
```

Answer (score 4):

For all databases, searching for user-defined stored procedures, views, functions, and table-valued functions, the following may help (based on Habo above):

```
declare @Sprocs as Table (DBName VarChar(64), SchemaName varchar (128), 
    StoredProcName VarChar(128), 
    type varchar(10), type_desc varchar(128), 
    create_date datetime, modify_date datetime, is_MS_Shipped int)
insert into @Sprocs
    execute sp_MSforeachdb N'use ?; select ''?'', 
        s.name as SchemaName, o.name as StoredProcName, 
        type, type_desc, create_date, modify_date, is_MS_Shipped
        from sys.all_objects as o inner join sys.schemas as s 
            on s.schema_id = o.schema_id 
        where o.type in (''P'', ''V'', ''PC'', ''FN'', ''TF'')
            and is_ms_shipped = 0'

select * from @Sprocs
where DBName not in ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb', 'dba') 
order by DBName, SchemaName, type, StoredProcName
```

Add 'U' to get user-generated tables as well.

Comment: Consider adding to the type filter 'FS' if you need to list CLR_SCALAR_FUNCTIONs and 'IF' if you need SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTIONs

Answer (score 3):

For a single database:

```
select s.name + '.' + p.name as sproc_name_with_schema
  from sys.procedures as p inner join
    sys.schemas as s on s.schema_id = p.schema_id
```

Did you need it for all databases?  Your question is a bit unclear on that.

```
declare @Sprocs as Table ( DBName VarChar(64), SprocName VarChar(128) )
insert into @Sprocs
  execute sp_MSforeachdb N'use ?; select ''?'', s.name + ''.'' + o.name from sys.all_objects as o inner join sys.schemas as s on s.schema_id = o.schema_id where o.type = ''P'''
select * from @Sprocs
```

Comment: Please don't recommend sp_msforeachdb. It's undocumented, unsupported, inflexible, and can skip databases. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/12/29/a-more-reliable-and-more-flexible-sp-msforeachdb.aspx https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/02/08/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior.aspx http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to first answer without temporal table and inserts:

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = '';
select 
    @sql += ' ' +
    'union all ' +
    'select ''' +
        dat.name + ''' as bas, b.name as sch, a.name as pro ' +
    'from ' +
        '[' + dat.name + '].[sys].procedures as a ' +
        'inner join [' + dat.name + '].[sys].schemas as b on a.schema_id = b.schema_id'
from sys.databases as dat;
set @sql = RIGHT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 11);
exec(@sql);
print @sql;
```